# How to prove this metric space is a complete metric space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

How to prove the metric space $L^{p}[a,b]$ is a complete metric space using the definition that says, Every Cauchy sequence in the metric space should converge to some point in that space? $$\left\{x(t)\in C[a,b] : \int_a^b |x(t)|^p \;dt < \infty \right\};$$ $$||x(t)||=\left[\int_a^b|x(t)|^p \;dt\right]^\frac{1}{p}$$

Comment: Is it a homework problem? What did you try?

Comment: Your description of $L^p[a,b]$ is inaccurate. The space  $L^p[a,b]$ of [$p$-integrable functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)is not the space of continuous function with finite $L^p$-norm. By the way: the result you ask about is called the [Riesz-Fischer theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz-Fischer_theorem)

Comment: Furthermore, your notation of the norm of $x$ is ugly. Maybe you forgot to take the closure of your space.

Comment: In that case it is complete by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching the internet. These are standard questions in functional analysis. You can find an answer at the below link.

- [Link](https://planetmath.org/ProofThatLpSpacesAreComplete)

Comment: thank you for your response.

Comment: Heads up, the link is now dead.

Answer (score 1):

Per t.b.'s comment, your space isn't $L^p[a,b]$. [$L^p[a,b]$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lp-Space.html) is the space of measurable functions that are $p$-integrable over $[a,b]$ (   $\int_a^b |f|^p<\infty$).

That these spaces are complete is known, to some,  as the Riesz-Fischer theorem.   The standard proof of this theorem uses the fact that a normed space is a Banach Space if and only if 
[every absolutely summable series is summable](http://books.google.com/books?id=BaEgbIoPTygC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=banach+absolutely+summable+series+is+summable&source=bl&ots=sA6RQTz45l&sig=bRTv3waYZm_vvSe_37fDA4SAv3g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4jrvTo6rCeGV0QHLgvHOCQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=banach%20absolutely%20summable%20series%20is%20summable&f=false).

If you want a proof that $L_p$ is complete, without using the above fact ("using Cauchy sequences", as you ask), see 
 [here](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~zhang24/RieszFischer.pdf) (this proof essentially incorporates that fact, though).

Comment: Thank you for your kind and quick response!

Comment: Heads up, the last link is now dead.